# Set data-id value into hiddenfield with multiple selectors

Tags: jquery, html

Got a simple question I guess. I have like a form in HTML which has multiple selectors that can be selected. In these selectors I have data attributes which can be selected (only one). If clicked, the data-attr must be stored into a hiddenfield.

My HTML:

```js
function styleChoice() {
    var productHandler = $('.styleChoiceButton');
    var setDataVal = $('#plantChoiceSelection');




    productHandler.bind('click', function (e) {
        var productDataStyle = productHandler.data('style');

        console.log('clicked');
        console.log(productDataStyle);
        console.log(e);

        productHandler.removeClass("is-selected");

        setDataVal.attr(productDataStyle);
        $(this).addClass("is-selected");

    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
                <button class="styleChoiceButton" type="button" data-style="style-one">
                    <figure>
                        <strong>Stijl 1</strong>
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" width="600" height="400" alt="productafbeeldingen" />
                    </figure>
                    <article>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula nulla, consequat laoreet vulputate ac, dictum ac dui. Nunc placerat tincidunt sollicitudin. Integer at libero leo. Praesent enim dolor, rhoncus consequat sapien vitae, maximus bibendum nunc. In consectetur leo vehicula porta vehicula. </p>
                    </article>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <button class="styleChoiceButton" type="button" data-style="style-two">
                    <figure>
                        <strong>Stijl 2</strong>
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" width="600" height="400" alt="productafbeeldingen" />
                    </figure>
                    <article>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula nulla, consequat laoreet vulputate ac, dictum ac dui. Nunc placerat tincidunt sollicitudin. Integer at libero leo. Praesent enim dolor, rhoncus consequat sapien vitae, maximus bibendum nunc. In consectetur leo vehicula porta vehicula. </p>
                    </article>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <button class="styleChoiceButton" type="button" data-style="style-three">
                    <figure>
                        <strong>Stijl 3</strong>
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" width="600" height="400" alt="productafbeeldingen" />
                    </figure>
                    <article>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula nulla, consequat laoreet vulputate ac, dictum ac dui. Nunc placerat tincidunt sollicitudin. Integer at libero leo. Praesent enim dolor, rhoncus consequat sapien vitae, maximus bibendum nunc. In consectetur leo vehicula porta vehicula. </p>
                    </article>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <button class="styleChoiceButton" type="button" data-style="style-four">
                    <figure>
                        <strong>Stijl 4</strong>
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" width="600" height="400" alt="productafbeeldingen" />
                    </figure>
                    <article>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula nulla, consequat laoreet vulputate ac, dictum ac dui. Nunc placerat tincidunt sollicitudin. Integer at libero leo. Praesent enim dolor, rhoncus consequat sapien vitae, maximus bibendum nunc. In consectetur leo vehicula porta vehicula. </p>
                    </article>
                </button>
            </div>
```

As you mentioned, which options I clicked, the only data-id i've get it style-one.

Appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: "As you mentioned, which options I clicked, the only data-id i've get it style-one." I don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: Sorry, i am not that good in English. But what I try to say is that the only value I got from clicking my option is data-style="style-one". So it wasn't indexing my data-id by the click event or something. Make this things more clear for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function styleChoice() {
        var productHandler = $('.styleChoiceButton');
        var setDataVal = $('#plantChoiceSelection');
        productHandler.bind('click', function (e) {
            var elem = $(this);
            var productDataStyle = elem.data('style');

            console.log('clicked');
            console.log(productDataStyle);

            productHandler.removeClass("is-selected");

            setDataVal.attr('data-selected', productDataStyle);
            elem.addClass("is-selected");

        });
    }
```

Comment: Please consider that `.bind` method is deprecated: `As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged. ` - jQuery API Documentation

Answer (score 0):

You should create listener for **each** `.styleChoiceButton`

```js
styleChoice();
function styleChoice() {
    var productHandler = $('.styleChoiceButton');
    var setDataVal = $('#plantChoiceSelection');




    productHandler.each(function() {
      $(this).bind('click', function (e) {
          var productDataStyle = $(this).data('style');

          console.log('clicked');
          console.log(productDataStyle);
  //        console.log(e);

          productHandler.removeClass("is-selected");

          setDataVal.attr(productDataStyle);
          $(this).addClass("is-selected");

      });
   });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
                <button class="styleChoiceButton" type="button" data-style="style-one">
                    <figure>
                        <strong>Stijl 1</strong>
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" width="600" height="400" alt="productafbeeldingen" />
                    </figure>
                    <article>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula nulla, consequat laoreet vulputate ac, dictum ac dui. Nunc placerat tincidunt sollicitudin. Integer at libero leo. Praesent enim dolor, rhoncus consequat sapien vitae, maximus bibendum nunc. In consectetur leo vehicula porta vehicula. </p>
                    </article>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <button class="styleChoiceButton" type="button" data-style="style-two">
                    <figure>
                        <strong>Stijl 2</strong>
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" width="600" height="400" alt="productafbeeldingen" />
                    </figure>
                    <article>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula nulla, consequat laoreet vulputate ac, dictum ac dui. Nunc placerat tincidunt sollicitudin. Integer at libero leo. Praesent enim dolor, rhoncus consequat sapien vitae, maximus bibendum nunc. In consectetur leo vehicula porta vehicula. </p>
                    </article>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <button class="styleChoiceButton" type="button" data-style="style-three">
                    <figure>
                        <strong>Stijl 3</strong>
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" width="600" height="400" alt="productafbeeldingen" />
                    </figure>
                    <article>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula nulla, consequat laoreet vulputate ac, dictum ac dui. Nunc placerat tincidunt sollicitudin. Integer at libero leo. Praesent enim dolor, rhoncus consequat sapien vitae, maximus bibendum nunc. In consectetur leo vehicula porta vehicula. </p>
                    </article>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <button class="styleChoiceButton" type="button" data-style="style-four">
                    <figure>
                        <strong>Stijl 4</strong>
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" width="600" height="400" alt="productafbeeldingen" />
                    </figure>
                    <article>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula nulla, consequat laoreet vulputate ac, dictum ac dui. Nunc placerat tincidunt sollicitudin. Integer at libero leo. Praesent enim dolor, rhoncus consequat sapien vitae, maximus bibendum nunc. In consectetur leo vehicula porta vehicula. </p>
                    </article>
                </button>
            </div>
```

Comment: This one doesn't work for me, the first answer does.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you should be able to do all this in simple JQuery:

```
$('.StyleChoiceButton').on('click', function(e) { 
    if ($(this)[0].hasAttribute('data-style')) {
        myhiddenfield = this.attributes['data-style'].value;
    }
});
```